# Updating yum package does not install minimal version of required package

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

Installing `pkg-a` which `Requires: pkg-common >= 1.1.0` does not update existing installed package `pkg-common` which is as version `1.0.0`.

**pkg-a Spec**

```
Name:     pkg-a
Version:  2.3.4
Requires: pkg-common >= 1.1.0
```

**pkg-common Spec**

```
Name:     pkg-common
Version:  1.1.0
```

**updating pkg-a**

```
> yum update pkg-a
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                      Arch                            Version                                     Repository                                    Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 pkg-a                                                        noarch                          2.3.4-1612802969                            my-repo                           22 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Update  1 Package
```

Note, no "updating for dependencies" listed for `pkg-common`.

Checking dependencies for `pkg-a`:

```
> yum deplist pkg-a | grep common
  dependency: pkg-common >= 1.1.0
   provider: pkg-common.x86_64 1.1.0-1612802885.el7
```

Checking for available versions of `pkg-common`, to be sure:

```
> yum list --show-duplicates pkg-common
pkg-common.x86_64    1.0.0-1611685722.el7   my-repo 
... 
pkg-common.x86_64    1.0.0-1611985057.el7   my-repo
pkg-common.x86_64    1.1.0-1612802885.el7   my-repo 

> yum list installed pkg-common
pkg-common.x86_64    1.0.0-1611985057.el7   my-repo
```

Additional (epoch) info about `pkg-common`:

```
# for old version 1.0.0
> rpm -qp --qf "%{epoch}:%{version}-%{release}" ./plk-common-1.0.0-1611985057.el7.x86_64.rpm
(none):1.0.0-1611985057.el7

# for new version 1.1.0
> rpm -q --qf "%{epoch}:%{version}-%{release}" pkg-common
(none):1.1.0-1612802885.el7
```

Note that `pkg-common-1.1.0` is known. Why is it not being installed when the dependent package is updated?

Comment: Add output of `yum list installed | grep pkg-common`

Comment: Sorry, naturally it did no copy the underline/color in the `list` command I executed. Will update for clarity, but it's an older (< 1.1.0) version that's installed.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when `pkg-common` uses Epoch. This is normally nearly invisible. See:

```
$ rpm -q perl
perl-5.32.0-465.fc33.x86_64

$ rpm -q --qf "%{epoch}:%{version}-%{release}" perl
4:5.32.0-465.fc33
```

`perl` on my machine has Epoch set to `4`. And Epoch always wins over version. See:

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp 4:5.32.0 9.0.0
4:5.32.0 > 9.0.0
```

Check if your `pkg-common` has some epoch set and then:

```
Requires: pkg-common >= X:1.1.0
```

Where `X` is the epoch number of `pkg-common`.

Comment: Thanks. There is no epoch -- see the bottom of my question (just updated).

Comment: Can you provide epoch of your old pkg-common (1.0.0)?

Comment: Sorry, updated above, but there is no epoch specified for the old or new package.